# Replacement for System.Web.MVC.AuthorizationContext in Net Core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, authorization

What is the replacement for System.Web.MVC.AuthorizationContext in Net Core 2?
I am migrating a .NET 4.6.2 project into NET ASP Core 2, am receiving error below:

```
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (IsAuthorized)
        {
            return;
        }

        UserManager userManager = new UserManager();
        Employee employee = userManager.GetByUsername(filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name);
```

Error:

> The type or namespace name 'AuthorizationContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you you are creating custom authorization filter, you could use `AuthorizationFilterContext`

```
public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)`
```

In asp.net core, we recommend to use `Policies` for custom AuthorizeAttribute.
We should use `AuthorizationHandlerContext`, refer to [Authorization Handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?highlight=authorizationcontext&view=aspnetcore-2.2#authorization-handlers).